# How to Delete uilabelview text appends three dots to the end in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uilabel

I have a UILabel which has UILabel attached to it. I add NSString value to it and each time for each cell after the text is over, it appends three dots to the end of the text file.
I am not sure why would I get that. Does any body have faced the similar problems:
Here I define my UILabel:

```
    UILabel *label1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 15, 15)];
    // set the label 
    label1.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    label1.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14];
    label1.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = NO;
    self.labelView1 = label1;
    [self.contentView addSubview:label1];
    [label1 release];
```

And I add the text as following.

```
labelView1.text = title;
labelView1.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = NO;
```

Comment: I don't understand your second sentence at all. However, a label with a width of 15 pixels isn't really going to be able to fit any text.

Comment: @Kevin: It will definately fit the text if I want to even if its 15 pixels and I have done that before also. I am sorry if I was not clear.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you don't want the label to append '...' when string does not fit label's size set label's `lineBreakMode` property to UILineBreakModeClip:

```
label1.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeClip;
```

Comment: Thank you. sometimes ur brain stop working even if it knows the answer.

Comment: Just in case someone hits it nowadays: label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByClipping; ;-)

Comment: As Conaaando says, UILineBreakModeClip is now deprecated in ios6.0

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the text is too long to fit the label and you've called

```
label1.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = NO;
```

which means the text will not be scaled down to fit.

With a width of `15`, you can barely fit one letter of font size `14`. Make the label bigger or size to fit (or both).